# update CheckBoxTreeCell styles from outside process

Tags: javafx, treeview

I am building my first javafx (2.2) application.  The user selects a number of tasks to execute, by selecting checkboxes in a treeview.

I am trying to figure out how, after a task completes, to change the style of the related TreeCell.

```
public class WorkbenchSscce extends Application {

    public static void main(String...args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootNode = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("parent");
        final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> taskOne = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("task one");
        final CheckBoxTreeItem<String> taskTwo = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("task two");
        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(taskOne, taskTwo);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(rootNode);
        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        Button executeButton = new Button("Execute");
        executeButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                if (taskOne.isSelected()) {
                    executeTask(1);
                    /**
                     * ?????
                     * give the TreeCell for taskOne a green background, to indicate it is complete
                     * ?????
                     */
                }
                if (taskTwo.isSelected()) {
                    executeTask(2);
                    /**
                     * ?????
                     * give the TreeCell for taskTwo a green background, to indicate it is complete
                     * ?????
                     */
                }
            }
        });
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(treeView, executeButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void executeTask(int input) {

        // do something
    }
}
```

I can see how to style the CheckBoxTreeCells at creation time.

I see how to change styles when *user* events happen to the TreeView (using EventListeners).

But I can't see how to style a tree cell when the source of the event is internal to the application.  See comments in the MouseEvent handler above.

Comment: You can't use a `SwingWorker` in JavaFX. JavaFX runs on a different UI thread to Swing. Have a look at the [Javadocs for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: @James_D: Thanks, I was wondering about that too.  Will that help me solve the problem in the post at all?  Other than working in the right thread that is.

Comment: Yes, `Task` has built in mechanisms for performing updates back on the FX Application Thread. Lots and lots of examples in the javadocs.

Comment: I changed my code to use Tasks, but I'm not much closer to solving the problem of styling TreeCells.

I can see how, if I wanted to update the name of the TreeItem, I could bind that property.  But I don't know how to translate that to update styles.

I updated my code with a more succinct example that focuses better on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to observe the state of the `Task` (I used a `Service` instead of a `Task` in this example, as it can be run multiple times) from the cell factory. To do this, you need the data type of the `TreeItem` to be something that has an observable property representing the current state of the task/service. The easiest way to do this, if you can, is to make the data type of the `TreeItem`s the `Task` itself (so conceptually, your `TreeView` is displaying `Task`s).

This is slightly subtle as the item (i.e. Task) represented by a given cell can change. In this example I just observe the cell's `item` property, removing a listener that observes the task's state from an item the cell is no longer representing and adding the listener to the item it now represents. If you use the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework (and Java 8, which it requires), you can clean this up a bit, doing something like

```
EasyBind.select(cell.itemProperty())
    .selectObject(Service::stateProperty)
    .addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> updateCell(cell) );
```

Full example (using JavaFX 2.2, though I compiled under Java 8, so some Java 8 features may have snuck in):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        final TreeView<SelectableService> tree = new TreeView<>();
        final TreeItem<SelectableService> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>(new SelectableService("Parent"));
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new SelectableService("Task "+i)));
        }
        tree.setRoot(treeRoot);

        final Button startButton = new Button("Start selected tasks");
        startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (SelectableService service : findSelectedTasks(treeRoot)) {
                    service.restart();
                }

            }
        });

        final HBox controls = new HBox(5);
        controls.getChildren().add(startButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        root.setCenter(tree);
        root.setBottom(controls);

        tree.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<SelectableService>, TreeCell<SelectableService>>() {

            @Override
            public TreeCell<SelectableService> call(TreeView<SelectableService> param) {
                return createCell();
            }

        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private CheckBoxTreeCell<SelectableService> createCell() {

        // CheckBoxTreeCell whose check box state is mapped to the selected property of the task:

        final CheckBoxTreeCell<SelectableService> cell = new CheckBoxTreeCell<SelectableService>(new Callback<TreeItem<SelectableService>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TreeItem<SelectableService> treeItem) {
                SelectableService task = treeItem.getValue();
                if (task != null) {
                    return task.selectedProperty();
                } else {
                    return null ;
                }
            }
        });

        final ChangeListener<State> taskStateListener = new ChangeListener<State>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends State> observable,
                    State oldValue, State newValue) {
                updateCell(cell);
            }

        };

        cell.itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<SelectableService>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends SelectableService> observable,
                    SelectableService oldTask, SelectableService newTask) {

                if (oldTask != null) {
                    oldTask.stateProperty().removeListener(taskStateListener);
                }

                if (newTask != null) {
                    newTask.stateProperty().addListener(taskStateListener);
                }

                updateCell(cell);
            }

        });

        cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<TreeItem<SelectableService>>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(TreeItem<SelectableService> treeItem) {
                SelectableService task = treeItem.getValue();
                if (task == null) {
                    return null ;
                } else {
                    return task.getName();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public TreeItem<SelectableService> fromString(String string) {
                // Not supported
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Uneditable tree cell does not create SelectableTasks");
            }

        });

        return cell;
    }

    private void updateCell(CheckBoxTreeCell<SelectableService> cell) {

        cell.getStyleClass().removeAll(Arrays.asList("running", "finished", "failed"));

        SelectableService task = cell.getItem();
        if (task != null) {
            State state = task.getState();

            // Update style class:
            if (state == State.RUNNING) {
                cell.getStyleClass().add("running");
            } else if (state == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                cell.getStyleClass().add("finished");
            } else if (state == State.FAILED){
                cell.getStyleClass().add("failed");
            }
        }

    }

    private Set<SelectableService> findSelectedTasks(TreeItem<SelectableService> treeItem) {
        Set<SelectableService> selectedTasks = new HashSet<>();
        addTaskAndChildTasksIfSelected(selectedTasks, treeItem) ;
        return selectedTasks ;
    }

    private void addTaskAndChildTasksIfSelected(Set<SelectableService> selectedTasks, TreeItem<SelectableService> treeItem) {
        SelectableService task = treeItem.getValue();
        if (task != null && task.isSelected()) {
            selectedTasks.add(task);
        }
        for (TreeItem<SelectableService> child : treeItem.getChildren()) {
            addTaskAndChildTasksIfSelected(selectedTasks, child);
        }
    }

    public static class SelectableService extends Service<Void> {
        private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "selected", false);

        public final BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
            return this.selected;
        }

        public final boolean isSelected() {
            return this.selectedProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setSelected(final boolean selected) {
            this.selectedProperty().set(selected);
        }

        private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(this, "name");

        private final void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return name.get() ;
        }

        public final ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public SelectableService(String name) {
            setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
                @Override
                public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.setDaemon(true);
                    return t ;
                }
            }));
            setName(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Task<Void> createTask()  {

            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    // just a mock task: pauses for a random time, then throws an exception with
                    // probability 0.25
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    Thread.sleep(2000 + rng.nextInt(2000));
                    if (rng.nextDouble() < 0.25) {
                        throw new Exception("Task failed");
                    }
                    return null ;                   
                }
            };

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

application.css is simply

```
.finished {
    -fx-background: green ;
}
.failed {
    -fx-background: red ;
}
.running {
    -fx-background: yellow ;
}
```

This is quite considerably cleaner in Java 8, by the way, but since you posted JavaFX 2.2-style code, I assumed you were still using the old version. Java 8 also allows you to use pseudoclasses for the css style, which is a bit nicer (and in general has better performance, though it's a moot point here).